# C# runtime compilation using multiple classes

Tags: c#

I want to compile a class that looks like this :

```c#
public class A 
{
    public MyProperties Property { get; set; }

    //other stuff
}

public class MyProperties
{
    string Property1 { get; set; }
    int Property2 { get; set; }
    double Property3 { get; set; }
    float Property4 { get; set; }
}
```

I can compile class `A` at runtime but:

- How can I make it so I can use class `MyProperties` after compiling class `A`? Would I need to make an instance of class `MyProperties`?
- How would I go about using class A which contains property from class MyProperties?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Something like 
A myClass = new A();
myClass.Property.Property1 = "123"; ?
Or rather inheritance?

Comment: I think where you have said 'compile' you might mean 'instantiate'?

Comment: I want to use Property from class A at runtime which uses class MyProperties.

Comment: It all happens during runtime, I'm using CodeDome for that

Comment: "CodeDome" is an actual company, but I assume you mean [CodeDOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/using-the-codedom). In which case it really helps to put this into context and tell us what problem you're actually trying to solve, because compiling classes like this looks like the proverbial cannon to shoot at a fly. You may be looking for XML/JSON configuration, anonymous types, `Dictionary`, AutoMapper, or `dynamic`. Run-time classes are very low on my personal list of things to consider solutions (and when I do, I use Reflection.Emit).

Comment: @Lucroth Just to make it clear, using CodeDom, you want to build `MyProperties`  and then build another class that has a `MyProperties` property, right? If so, you have to build a `CodeMemberProperty` which `Type` property is `CodeTypeReference` based on `MyProperties`

Comment: @vc74 Exactly, but how can I build multiple classes at once? I can only create instance of a class but how can I "connect" them?

Comment: Once you've built the first one you should be able to reference it while building the second one using `CodeTypeReference`

Answer (score 1):

When class A is instantiated all its properties have default value. `Property` will be null and you need to assign its value.
You can do it from your code or set it in A's constructor:

```
public A()
{
   this.Properties = new MyProperties();
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to build `MyProperties` and `A` dynamically, at runtime

Comment: @vc74 what's the difference? `Property` will be null anyway

Comment: I think he wants to build `MyProperties` dynamically and then reference it when building `A`. He's using CodeDom and not C# to build his classes.

Answer (score 0):

I propose 2 changes, first initialize your Property in the A class constructor, second, make MyProperty members public :

```
public class A 
{
    public MyProperties Property { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        Property = new MyProperties();
    }
    //other stuff
}

public class MyProperties
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
    public double Property3 { get; set; }
    public float Property4 { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have these changes, you can use your class like this :

```
var a = new A();
a.Property.Property1 = "Hello world";
Console.WriteLine (a.Property.Property1);
```